# Enter regular command in evil insert state?

Tags: evil

I'm using `evil` (specifically via `spacemacs`).  Is there a way to enter a regular command without leaving `insert` state? For example, running `SPC i u` (for adding unicode character) while still in `insert` state?

Comment: All key commands of emacs are just a function call. Why don't you press `M-x` and then input the relevant function instead？If you don't remember the function name, `C-h k` will help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you want, but there is a way to execute *one*
command and then return to `insert state`. Press `C-o`
(`evil-execute-in-normal-state`) which puts you in a state where the next
keybinding will be executed in `normal state`, and then you will be returned to
`insert state`. For example, while in `insert state`, press `C-o` and then `SPC
f y`. This will display the path of the current file in the echo area (and copy
it to the kill ring) and leave you in `insert state`.

At the very least, this should be a good way to deal with your *insert Unicode character* example

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for!